# max time a report should take to generate report

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

I am just curious to know how long, in minutes, does the reporting service take to generate report when it returns 1MB of data. Maybe using views and table is properly index. SSRS reporting  and server side generation.

Comment: A question this general really can't be answered.  It can vary greatly, depending on things like how much data has to be processed to generated this 1MB report, how well-indexed said data is, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Report generation time has two components:
 - Data Acquisition time
 - Render Time

So for 1 Mb of data, how many records (rows) are we talking? How many pages will the report have?  How many controls per page?  Does the report use charting?  These are the factors that will determine generation time.

For **most** reports, data acquisition time is the most significant factor.  Your report is never going to run faster than the raw data acquisition.  So if you are using SQL, the report can't generate faster than the time required to run the query.  I have seen queries that return far more than 1Mb of data very quickly.  I have also seen queries that return very little data, that run for a long time.

On the render side, there are a couple of things that that can cause a report to run be slow.  The first is in report aggregation.  If a report needs to receive all of the records prior to starting rendering, then its performance will suffer.  In particular, depending on the reporting tool.  With large data sets (more than 10,000 records), you can have significant improvements in rendering by doing aggregation at the source (DB).  The other is charting, which typically involves heavy rendering overhead and aggregation.

Most reporting systems allow you to build in timers or logging that will help you to performance tune the report.  It is best to build timers into the report that will tell you what percentage of time the report is spending getting the data, and what percentage is spent rendering. When you have this information, you will know where to focus your energies.

If you are really trying to evaluate the performance of the reporting tool, the best way is to build a report that either reads a flat file or generates the data through code.  In other words, eliminate the impact of the database and see how fast your reporting tool can generate pages.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

How long is acceptable? Depends on what it's doing, how much it's run, things like that. Anything below 30 seconds would be fine if it's run once every day or two. If it's run once a week or once a month that number could be a lot higher.

Answer (score 1):

The report itself is generally very fast, if you're seeing a hangup you may want to check the execution time of the query which generates the data.  A complex query can take a long time, even if it only returns a little data...

Answer (score 0):

I've found, when using BIRT and other reporting systems that the best improvements tend to come by offloading most of the work to the database at the back end.

In other words, don't send lots of data across the wire and sort or group it locally.  The database is almost certainly going to outperform you with its SQL orderby and groupby clauses and optimizing indexes (among other things).

That way, you get faster extraction of the data you want AND less network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

As several said already, a general question like this really can't be answered. However, I wrote up [Turbo-charge Your Report Speed – General Rules & Guidelines](http://blogs.windwardreports.com/davidt/2010/12/turbo-charge-your-report-speed-general-rules-guidelines.html) (disclaimer - I'm the CTO at Windward Reports, a competitor of SSRS). I think that will help you look for what you can do to speed up the process.

And with all the caveats about the specifics matter a lot, on a 3GHz workstation we generally see 7-30 pages/second. Keep in mind this is numbers for Windward, not SSRS.